# Azure Web Job Deployment

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, role

Getting

`C:\Git\project\packages\Microsoft.Web.WebJobs.Publish.1.0.7\tools\webjobs.console.targets(110,5): Error : An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: No website could be found which matches the WebSiteName [project-dev] and WebSiteUrl [http://project.azurewebsites.net] supplied.`

Looks like job is published but scheduled is not created.

I suspected that issue is my `access rights`, i'm in `contributor` on Azure subscription, as it works fine for my collegue that is subscription `owner`

But according to 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/role-based-access-control-what-is

**Contributor** can create and manage all types of Azure resources but can’t grant access to others.

I use VS2015 (v14.0.25431 Update 3).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The integration with the Azure Scheduler is no longer supported, and not present at all in VS2017 (please upgrade to that if possible). Instead, scheduling is achieved via the `settings.job` file and CRON expressions. See [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/web-sites-create-web-jobs) for details (search for 'CRON expressions').